# Call 2 or more functions inside a match expression

Tags: ocaml

I am a beginner in OCaml. I am curious to know how, syntactically speaking, call two functions, or more, within a match expression. Or is that possible at all?

For example :

```ml
let rec foo l:list = 
  match l with
  | [x,y] -> (foo1 x) (foo2 y)
  | _ -> doSome
```

I have tried using the `;` operator but that seems to be used for something else. I have tried different combinations of bracketing but in all cases I get
*This is not a function it cannot be applied* under `foo1 x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a semicolon (no begin/end). You don't need the parentheses (they don't hurt but they're not especially idiomatic OCaml).

```
let rec foo l : 'a list = match l with
| [x,y] -> foo1 x; foo2 y
| _ -> doSome
```

Comment: This is good, but please note, @hexaquark that the type annotation on your `foo` function should be unnecessary, as OCaml will infer the return type of `foo` from the return type of `foo2`. If that and the type of `doSome` do not agree, you should see compilation errors.